# need to fix the bootstrap navigation bar to fixed while scroll down

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

**I need to fix the below bootstrap code to fixed on the top of a web page while scrolling down. How can it do? please help me..**

Here the bootstrap code that I have. Please help me to change this code from static to fixed while scrolling down the web page.

```
     <div class="header_top" id="home">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right mx-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#menu">Menu</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        Drop Down
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="404.html">Services</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: add `navbar-fixed-top` class in your `nav`

Comment: not working .. please check the updated code

Comment: @AshishJoseph I recommand you to check my comment and to see if you miss something (like script or links)

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

...

read this document for more details
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Answer (score 0):

you can use css:

```
nav{
    position: fixed;
}
```

actually what was written behind the class  `navbar-fixed-top`

Comment: check if you have all requireds: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=navbar-fixed-to-top

Comment: can you add jsfiddle then it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can add:`<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">`

```
data-spy="affix" data-offset-fop="scroll amount"
```

You can see this link for example: 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_affix&stacked=h

Another example: https://www.codeply.com/go/LDHQhWUG0x